# Show that $\mu(E) = 0)$ iff $\mu(E \cap E(n)) =0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathbb{T} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1\}$. Define $\phi:[0,1] \to \mathbb{T}$ by $\phi(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$, let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and define $\mu$ by $\mu(E)= m(\phi^{-1}(E))$ for each Borel set $E$ of $\mathbb{T}$.

Suppose $\theta$ is irrational and $E$ is a Borel set of $\mathbb{T}$. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $E(n) = \{ze^{2n\theta\pi i}: z \in E\}$. Show that $\mu(E) = 0)$ iff $\mu(E \cap E(n)) =0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

---

I've already shown that $\mu$ is a measure, and the forward direction of this is trivial. My intuition is that I might be able to show that if $E \neq \emptyset$, $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}E(n)\right) = 1$$ I think this has something to do with $\theta$ being irrational, and that if I fix a $z \in E$, the set $\{ze^{2k\theta \pi i}:k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ should be dense in $\mathbb{T}$. Then from there I think that I could get $$\mu(E) = \mu\left(E \cap \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}E(n)\right) \leq \mu(E \cap E(n)) = 0$$ but I don't know how to fill in the details or even if that is a good idea.

Comment: Since $\theta$ is irrational, for any point $z \in \mathbb{T}$ we will have that $ze^{2n\theta\pi i} \neq ze^{2m\theta\pi i}$ whenever $n \neq m$ (including when either $n$ or $m$ equals zero). If you ask me, I think your best bet is to suppose $\mu(E \cap E(n)) =0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and assume towards a contradiction that $\mu(E)>0$.

Comment: @MattAPelto Thanks for your help. I had started with trying to do this by contradiction, but I didn't know what to do with $\mu(E)>0$. I was trying to think of how $E(n)$ would intersect with $E$ in that case but I couldn't get very far in that direction. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: Well for any interval $I \subset [0,1]$, the image set $\phi(I)$ will be an arc of $\mathbb{T}$. So if we were to let $E=\phi(I)$ (or rather $E(0)$) then $E(n)$ will be an arc of $\mathbb{T}$, and in fact the arc is obtained by simply rotating $E(n-1)$ by $2\theta\pi$. So at least in this hypothetical scenario, I believe you should be able to show $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}E(n)=\mathbb{T}$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html?fbclid=IwAR12y8MquZ5xrJOgafyjNObjLi45MMoFYO_kvEljauZDk1GxGgtcLOZaPoU